# Imprimir variável dentro de uma estrutura de repetição

Tags: java, variáveis

Não está reconhecendo a variável `soma` porque ela está dentro do *loop*. O que eu faço para consertar isso?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int tipo;

    int restante = 0;
    int bim = 4;
    //double soma= 0;

    double[] nota = new double[bim];

    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("inisira a quatidade de bimestres");
    bim = x.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < bim; i++) {
        System.out.println("Insira a nota do " + (i + 1) + "º Bimestre");
        nota[i] = x.nextDouble();
        double soma = 0;
        soma = soma + nota[i];

    }

    double media = soma / bim;
    System.out.println(media);
}
```

Comment: Colocando a variavel fora do loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acostume-se a declarar a variável onde ela será necessária. E entenda o que está acontecendo com seu código. Se fizer um teste de mesa verá que já está errado porque todo passo do laço a variável será zerada e não é isso que você quer, não faz o menor sentido em usar assim, e você tinha começado fazer certo, depois estragou :(. E não use variáveis sem necessidade. Veja como fica mais simples:

```
import java.util.*;

class Ideone {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("inisira a quatidade de bimestres");
        int bim = x.nextInt();
        double soma = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < bim; i++) {
            System.out.println("Insira a nota do " + (i + 1) + "º Bimestre");
            soma += x.nextDouble();
        }
        System.out.println(soma / bim);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/wcnT9s). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rzoaklqj-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/Looping.java).

Answer (score 4):

Um conceito importante em programação chama-se escopo. Em Java, ele é definido pelos `curly braces`, os `{ }`, mas vamos chamá-los de bloco, ou seja, cada par de `{ }` é um bloco e, como você deve já ter notado, você pode ter um bloco dentro de outro. Se não notou, perceba essa estrutura típica de uma classe em Java:

```
class Pessoa {

   public void chamarPeloNome(String nome) {

      if(nome != null) {
         System.out.println("Olá, " + nome);
      }
   }
}
```

Veja que a classe tem um bloco, o método tem um bloco e o `if` dentro do método tem um bloco, sendo o do if o bloco mais interno e o da classe o mais externo.

Isso posto, a regra geral em Java diz que variáveis definidas dentro de um bloco só são visíveis dentro desse mesmo bloco ou em blocos que sejam internos a este.

Observe seu código:

```
(...)
for (int i = 0; i < bim; i++) {
        System.out.println("Insira a nota do " + (i + 1) + "º Bimestre");
        nota[i] = x.nextDouble();
        double soma = 0;
        soma = soma + nota[i];

    }

    double media = soma / bim;
```

A variável `soma` está definida num bloco, mas você está tentando acessá-la num bloco mais externo, e isso é impossível em Java, pois, como dissemos, uma variável é acessível no mesmo bloco em que ela é declarada ou em blocos internos a ele, nunca em blocos externos.

Como resolver então? Simples. Basta declarar essa variável fora do `for`. Do jeito que está hoje, ela só é visível lá dentro e qualquer outro bloco dentro do `for` que você eventualmente criasse (um `if`, por exemplo).

Answer (score 0):

Coloque a declaração da variável soma fora do laço de repetição **for**.

```
double soma = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < bim; i++) {
     System.out.println("Insira a nota do " + (i + 1) + "º Bimestre");
     nota[i] = x.nextDouble();        
     soma = soma + nota[i];
}
```

Comment: *"Não é uma boa prática declarar variáveis dentro de laços de repetição"* - Eu diria que depende. Se a variável só vai ser usada dentro do laço, não há problema (e dependendo do caso é até melhor, pois aí limita-se o escopo dela). Se ela for usada fora do laço (como é o caso desta pergunta), aí não é nem questão de "boa prática", é porque não faz sentido mesmo :-)

Comment: Discordo desta afirmação final, não existe "boa pratica", existe o que faz sentido lógico e o que não faz. Como explicado pelo @hkotsubo, há situações onde isso faz todo o sentido.

Comment: A linha de texto antes do código está certa. A que está depois, totalmente errada.

Comment: Luan, por que você acha que é má prática?

Comment: Eu havia lido que fazendo essa declaração dentro do laço, faz com que seja criado sempre uma nova variável na memoria a cada iteração. Entra no laço, cria-se a variável alocando espaço em memoria pra ela, usa a variável conforme a lógica dentro do laço, no final do laço essa variável "é jogada fora", na próxima interação do laço ele criaria uma "nova" variável do mesmo tipo e nome. Então ficaria "destruindo e criando" uma variável a cada iteração, na qual poderia ser reusada.

Comment: Seria essa a minha justificativa: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803674/declaring-variables-inside-or-outside-of-a-loop

Comment: As respostas desse link dizem que é melhor declarar a variável no menor escopo possível. Ou seja, se ela é usada somente dentro do laço, declare-a dentro. Se ela é usada fora, declare-a fora. Em nenhum momento disseram que *"Não é uma boa prática declarar variáveis dentro de laços de repetição"* (na verdade sugerem o contrário, se for o caso). Mais ainda, uma das respostas viu que não faz diferença no bytecode e o suposto ganho de performance (ao evitar o ciclo "cria-destroi" que vc mencionou) é irrelevante.

Comment: Verdade, faz sentido, entendi, obrigado =)

Answer (score -2):

No Java existe uma forte tipagem, a sua variável `soma` foi declarada internamente no laço `for`, ou seja, ela esta visível apenas dentro do laço. Caso você queira utilizar ela fora do laço `for`, aconselho declarar ela fora do laço:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int tipo;

    int restante = 0;
    int bim = 4;
    double soma = 0;


    double[] nota = new double[bim];

    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("inisira a quatidade de bimestres");
    bim = x.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < bim; i++) {
        System.out.println("Insira a nota do " + (i + 1) + "º Bimestre");
        nota[i] = x.nextDouble();
        soma = soma + nota[i];

    }

    double media = soma / bim;
    System.out.println(media);
}
```